# I'm getting this error for strcpy

Tags: c++, fstream, strcpy

I'm getting these errors. On the first line and second line, it says No matching function for call to 'strcpy', i'm pretty sure im using the wrong preprocessor directive, I'm using #include < fstream>

```
void writeStudents(vector<student> &studentVector){
ifstream studentinfo;
studenttowrite allinfo;
studentinfo.open("students.bin");
for (unsigned int x=0 ; x<studentVector.size(); x++) {
    allinfo.StuNo = studentVector[x].StuNo;
    strcpy(allinfo.FirstName, studentVector[x].FirstName);
    strcpy(allinfo.LastName, studentVector[x].LastName);
    allinfo.major = studentVector[x].major;
    allinfo.college = studentVector[x].college;
    allinfo.Age     = studentVector[x].Age;
    allinfo.Gpa     = studentVector[x].Gpa;
    studentinfo.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>
                    (&studentVector[x]), sizeof(student));
}
```

Comment: Show us the `studenttowrite` and `student` types.

Comment: `std::strcpy` is in `<cstring>`. But consider using `std::string` from `<string>` instead of C-style strings. They're much easier to handle.

Comment: As @Wintermute hinted at, you could be forgetting the include. Please show your includes as well. Next time, try to create an MCVE example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why do you set up `allinfo` then never use it?

Answer (score 0):

To use `std::strcpy()` (equivalent of C `strcpy()`) function including `fstream` is not enough, you must include `cstring`:

```
#include <cstring>
```

Also (not knowing what types are `student` and `allinfo.FirstName`, `allinfo.LastName`) arguments of `std::strcpy()` must be convertible to `char*` and `const char*`.

Comment: Add that it should be `std::strcpy` and I'm in.